# Unspecified error while opening a connection to database

Tags: vb6

Good eve guys.
I'm having a problem with my code.

The goal is, when I type a letter in the combobox, it wiill show a list of possible model names.

But whenever I type in that combobox, it gives me an error.

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
Private Sub cmbSearch_Change()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim record As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim model As String

model = cmbSearch.Text

If cmbSearch.Text <> "" Then

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database.mdb"

    cmbSearch.Clear

     record.Open "SELECT Model FROM LaptopSpecs WHERE Model LIKE '" & model & "%' ORDER BY Model", conn, 3, 3

        If record.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Do While Not record.EOF
                cmbSearch.AddItem record.Fields("Model").Value
                record.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        cmbSearch.Text = model
    End If

Set record = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the part conn.open, the error message pops up.

> run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)': unspecified error

Comment: When this error occurs, inspect the connection's error collection.  It will probably have more informative error codes and messages as to what is wrong with your connection attempt.

Comment: Have you even tried compiling this code in Access? Problems: 
(1) There is no Access object named `App`. The Access `Application` object has no property named `Path`
(2) Access `ComboBox` objects have no method named `Clear`
(3) Using the ADO `RecordCount` property could cause a significant slowdown
(4) Opening up a Connection object with every user keystroke is wasteful and slow

Comment: VBA is not VB6.  Please don't put irrelevant tags on questions like this.

Comment: @MarkL im not sure where i can get more information about the error. i tried searching about it but all the errors just caused that the connection from vb6 to database is closed. the other forms in  my program also uses the same connection but runs smoothly. Thank you for helping btw. will find more info about it.

Comment: @kismert the connection or codes i used in that codes is the same codes i used in the other forms, that is running smoothly. ill try to find another way to achieve this goal. but first, ill try to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Assuming you are using Access:</del>
This question isn't about Access, but if it where:

Expanding on this answer, I recommend removing *all* the code in your example, and replacing it with this (done in Form design mode):

1. Set the `cmbSearch.RowSource` property to a fixed query like:

   ```
   SELECT Model FROM LaptopSpecs ORDER BY Model
   ```
2. Set the cmbSearch `Auto Expand` to True.

This will work for 98% of all ComboBox type-to-select scenarios, and should work for your example.

Comment: theres no auto expand in my cmbsearch properties. i tried your code. but still the same error. Thanks again man. really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using Access? If yes, see expanded answer above. If no, tell us what you are using! (And remove the Access tag from your question!)